# Concourse CI can't find kubernetes secrets

Tags: kubernetes, concourse, kubernetes-secrets

I'm receiving the following error when the runner is trying to retrieve a resource:

```
checking failed -
Expected to find variables: git
```

my resource looks similar to:

```
- name: resource-repo
  type: git
  source:
    uri: https://[url]
    branch: master
    tag_filter: '*'
    username: ((git.username))
    password: ((git.password))
```

my values.yaml for the helm chart includes:

```
rbac:
  create: false

credentialManager:
  kubernetes:
    namespacePrefix: concourse
```

(regardless, the release name is concourse)

under namespace `concourse-main` i have the the secret:

```
Details
Name: git
Namespace: concourse-main
Type: Opaque

Data
password:  bytes
username:  bytes
```

further information:

- k8s 1.8.6
- kops 1.8.1
- weavenet
- Concourse 3.9.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on information from the [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/concourse#kubernetes-secrets):

> By default, this chart will use Kubernetes Secrets as a credential manager. For a given Concourse team, a pipeline will look for secrets in a namespace named [namespacePrefix][teamName]. The namespace prefix is the release name hyphen by default, and can be overridden with the value `credentialManager.kubernetes.namespacePrefix`.

In your configuration, I see the secret in a [namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/) of your secret is `concourse-main`, but a default `namespacePrefix` is `concourse`.

So, Concourse trying to get your secret from a wrong namespace.

You can fix it using two ways:

1. Create a secret in the namespace `concourse`.
2. Change `namespacePrefix` to `concourse-main`.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. To which container am i supposed to link the variables? from the documentation it looks like Concourse is supposed to be pulling the variables on its own:  https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/concourse#kubernetes-secrets

Comment: @Deano yep, it using them directly, I updated my answer