# Using k8s secrets in concourse pipeline

Tags: concourse, kubernetes-secrets, concourse-git-resource

This question is similar to this one [Concourse CI can't find kubernetes secrets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432041/concourse-ci-cant-find-kubernetes-secrets) . However, the marked solution in it did not work for me.

I have setup concourse using this helm chart https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/concourse

My release name is `concourse-ci`. So, my namespace prefix is `concourse-ci-` and the team name is `main`.

So, following the documentation https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/concourse#kubernetes-secrets I created my secrets like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: git
  namespace: concourse-ci-main
type: Opaque
data: #Base 64 (can be removed)
  username: <base64 encoded username>
  password: <base64 encoded password>
```

In mu pipeline, I have the following:

```
resources:
- name: my-repo
  type: git
  source:
    uri: <my-uri>
    branch: develop
    username: ((git.username))
    password: ((git.password))
```

When, I execute the pipeline with the above code, it gets' stuck. However, if I replace `((git.username))` and `((git.password))` with the actual values, it works perfectly fine.

Am I missing something? I tried creating the secret in `concourse-ci` instead of `concourse-ci-main`, but I still get the same error.

I have the following in `values.yml`

```
kubernetes:
  enabled: true
```

and

```
rbac:
  # true here enables creation of rbac resources
  create: false
```